# I can't identify this semi-cursive kanji

Tags: kanji

So I'm reading this manga and I am suddenly hit with a semi-cursive kanji which I need some more practice to get use to it. I tried checking the radicals but to no avail. I have no idea what it is.

**世に＿れる**

I was thinking it might be something with this radical"彳" but I still didn't get it.

[image]

Comment: Maybe it is 紛れる?

Comment: @AlexanderZ., the stroke order for the right-hand 分 portion would be wrong, since the second-to-last stroke in the image is the center-to-left downward, while in 分, that stroke is the final one.  No?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Google image search 分 行書, that’s just the way it is in semicursive

Comment: @AlexanderZ. that made totally sense and I have a semi-cursive font(分行書) and it is indeed that after I typed it out. Thanks!

Comment: @dROOOze, thanks for the confirmation.  Cheers!

Comment: @AlexanderZ., I suggest you post your comment as an actual answer.  :)

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi I totally forgot to mention, the abbreviation 刂 (e.g. in 利 and its *kana* descendants り and リ) is also written with a stroke order reverse to 刀. This order was present for 刀 since a long time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably [紛]{まぎ}れる. Here is a similar gyosho specimen: [image]